# MySQL: count of unique products for certain categories

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables:

- `products`
- `categories`
- `category_product` (for 'many-to-many' relationship).

Example of 'category_product' table:

```
+-------------+------------+
| category_id | product_id |
+-------------+------------+
|           3 |          9 |
|           3 |         28 |
|           3 |        100 |
|         ... |        ... |
|           7 |         13 |
|           7 |         21 |
|           7 |         81 |
|           7 |        100 |
|         ... |        ... |
|          25 |         22 |
|          25 |         28 |
|          25 |        100 |
+-------------+------------+
```

I need to find count of unique products in this categories. In my case I have to exclude from `COUNT` rows, where `product_id = 28` and 100. How to do this?

Comment: Why would a category have non-unique products? Does `category_product` have a composite key defined?

Comment: Because there is such a condition: one product can belong to different categories.
Composite key is defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to exclude products that belong to more than 1 categories:

```
SELECT cp.category_id, COUNT(*) counter
FROM category_product cp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM category_product WHERE product_id = cp.product_id AND category_id <> cp.category_id)
GROUP BY cp.category_id
```

Or use this query that returns the `product_id`s that belong to only 1 category:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM category_product
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
```

as a subquery with the operator `IN`:

```
SELECT category_id, COUNT(*) counter
FROM category_product
WHERE product_id IN (
  SELECT product_id
  FROM category_product
  GROUP BY product_id
  HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
GROUP BY category_id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=e943b811c458e1a33cb080a1b2636221).
Results:

```
category_id | counter
----------: | ------:
          3 |       1
          7 |       3
         25 |       1
```

Comment: Thank you forpas! This is what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work:

```
SELECT
    c.*,
    COALESCE( cnts.distinct_product_count, 0 ) AS distinct_product_count
FROM
    categories AS c
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT
            category_id,
            COUNT( DISTINCT product_id ) AS distinct_product_count
        FROM
            category_product
        WHERE
            product_id NOT IN ( 28, 100 )
        GROUP BY
            category_id

    ) AS cnts ON
        cnts.category_id = c.category_id
```

Answer (score 0):

USE a Count an DISTINCT

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE category_product (
  `category_id` INTEGER,
  `product_id` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO category_product
  (`category_id`, `product_id`)
VALUES
  ('3', '9'),
  ('3', '28'),
  ('3', '100'),
  ('7', '13'),
  ('7', '21'),
  ('7', '81'),
  ('7', '100'),
  ('25', '22'),
  ('25', '28'),
  ('25', '100');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT product_id)  FROM category_product
WHERE `category_id` IN (3,7,25);

| COUNT(DISTINCT product_id) |
| -------------------------- |
| 7                          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4UcjKhTvzzNQWL3Pfkfew4/6)